# Showing NatTable context menu

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I use NatTable. How to show context menu item on certain condition depending on the content of the cell? And how to select cell over which context menu was called? I bind menu with the following code

```
uiBindingRegistry.registerMouseDownBinding(
            new MouseEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, null, MouseEventMatcher.RIGHT_BUTTON), new PopupMenuAction(menu));
```

**UPD:**
I create menu like this, but 'Test' item is visible in spite of `isActive` always return `false`. What's wrong with it?

```
menu = new PopupMenuBuilder(natTable).withMenuItemProvider(ITEM_ID, new IMenuItemProvider() {
        @Override
        public void addMenuItem(final NatTable natTable, final Menu popupMenu) {
            final MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.PUSH);
            menuItem.setText("Test");
            menuItem.setEnabled(true);
            menuItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            });
        }
    }).withVisibleState(ITEM_ID, new IMenuItemState() {
        @Override
        public boolean isActive(final NatEventData natEventData) {
            return false;
        }
    }).build();
```

Comment: If the constant ITEM_ID is not null, there is nothing wrong with that code. The question is, where do you create the menu? I create it directly in the AbstractUiBindingConfiguration and it works as intended.

Comment: @Dirk Fauth I've found the reason. In `CellPopupMenuAction` `run()` I have `menu.setData(event.data)` but there should be `menu.setData(MenuItemProviders.NAT_EVENT_DATA_KEY, event.data)`. Then everything works as intended.

Comment: thanks for the hint ... I completely forgot about that detail. I updated the example code in my answer to reflect that correctly.

Comment: I have found the reason again https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=451490 Which version of Eclipse/JFace are you using?

Comment: @Dirk Fauth 4.3.0/3.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answer is correct. Although it can be improved. You don't need the SelectionLayer.

```
class CellPopupMenuAction implements IMouseAction {

    private final Menu menu;

    public CellPopupMenuAction(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(NatTable natTable, MouseEvent event) {
        int columnPosition = natTable.getColumnPositionByX(event.x);
        int rowPosition = natTable.getRowPositionByY(event.y);

        ILayerCell cell = natTable.getCellByPosition(columnPosition, rowPosition);

        if (!cell.getDisplayMode().equals(DisplayMode.SELECT)) {
            natTable.doCommand(
                    new SelectCellCommand(
                            natTable,
                            columnPosition,
                            rowPosition,
                            false,
                            false));
        }

        menu.setData(MenuItemProviders.NAT_EVENT_DATA_KEY, event.data);
        menu.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This way you completely remove the need to reference the SelectionLayer and even improve the functionality because the SelectCellCommand is never fired if you right click on a selected cell.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I show different items in menu depending on condition (cell content)?

Comment: If you are using the NatTable PopupMenuBuilder you can create and add a IMenuItemState to specify the conditions for enabled or visible states.

Comment: I use MenuManager. Is there way to use IMenuItemState  in this case?

Comment: In fact you need the MenuManager to create the PopupMenuBuilder to make use of IMenuItemState. For NatTable context menus with access to the NatTable contents this is always the recommended way.

Comment: Could you please look at updated question? Menu item is always visible though I use IMenuItemState which is always false

Comment: One more further question. Is there a way to get this menu from test framework? I can get reference to NatTable (and even show this menu) but have no idea how to get reference to it.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without modifications right now. The menu is not set to the NatTable instance but kept in the action. This is by design since this enables you to have multiple different menus in one NatTable based on different conditions (e.g. different grid regions). You could try a workaround using a menu listener on your menu that adds the menu via NatTable#setMenu() on showing the menu and removing that on hiding the menu. This way it will be accessible when it is visible. But I haven't tested that yet, it is just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My first approach was to call NatTable#setMenu() once menu was built. But in test I have menu without items. When I call NatTable#setMenu() in MenuListener as you have suggested, I get what I want

Answer (score 1):

You need IMouseAction to select cell. An example code from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/805765/) and some additional code added inside it to select call added over it below :

```
nattable.addConfiguration( new AbstractUiBindingConfiguration()

    uiBindingRegistry.registerMouseDownBinding( new MouseEventMatcher( SWT.NONE, GridRegion.BODY,
                            MouseEventMatcher.RIGHT_BUTTON ), new CellPopupMenuAction(menu, selectionLayer) );


});

class CellPopupMenuAction implements IMouseAction {

                private final Menu menu;
                private final SelectionLayer selectionLayer;

                public CellPopupMenuAction(Menu menu, SelectionLayer selectionLayer) {
                    this.menu = menu;
                    this.selectionLayer = selectionLayer;
                }

                @Override
                public void run(NatTable natTable, MouseEvent event) 
                {
                    if( selectionLayer.getSelectedRowCount() <= 1 )
                            {
                                int colPosition = LayerUtil.convertColumnPosition( natTable,
                                        natTable.getColumnPositionByX( event.x ), selectionLayer );
                                int rowPosition = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition( natTable,
                                        natTable.getRowPositionByY( event.y ), selectionLayer );

                                natTable.doCommand( new SelectCellCommand( selectionLayer, colPosition, rowPosition, false,
                                        false ) );
                            }
                    menu.setData(event.data);
                    menu.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
```

I assume you have the selectionLayer as a private variable in your code.

Comment: Thanks for selection sell, it works exactly as I want. I've looked at provided link and as far as I understand it shows menu on condition. But I need to show different items in menu depending on condition. And I still have no idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I used SomeDude's answer above and it worked but the menu item was displaying before the selection which looked odd. I moved the menu display to a UI thread asyncExec call and selection occurs first then the menu appears on top of it -

```
@Override
public void run(NatTable natTable, MouseEvent event) {

    if (selectionLayer.getSelectedRowCount() <= 1) {

        int colPosition = LayerUtil.convertColumnPosition(natTable, natTable.getColumnPositionByX(event.x),
                selectionLayer);

        int rowPosition = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition(natTable, natTable.getRowPositionByY(event.y),
                selectionLayer);

        natTable.doCommand(new SelectCellCommand(selectionLayer, colPosition, rowPosition, false, false));

    }

    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            menu.setData(event.data);
            menu.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```