# How to resolve Nattable conflicts between DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration and ButtonCellPainter on left mouse keydown event?

Tags: nattable

I am developing an RCP Application, and am using Nebula's NatTable for that. I configer row selection (use DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration) , and configer cell button (use ButtonCellPainter) . the both ui bing left mouse down event.

What I want is:

When i click the left mouse button, the button responds to the event while the button of whole row is selected.

Below part code:

```
selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(columnHideShowLayer,false);
selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(new RowSelectionModel<Row>(selectionLayer, bodyDataProvider,
                new IRowIdAccessor<Row>() {
                    @Override
                    public Serializable getRowId(Row rowObject) {
                        return rowObject.getStatus();
                    }
                }));
selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration());


class ButtonClickConfiguration<T> extends AbstractUiBindingConfiguration {

    private final ButtonCellPainter buttonCellPainter;

    public ButtonClickConfiguration(ButtonCellPainter buttonCellPainter) {
        this.buttonCellPainter = buttonCellPainter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureUiBindings(UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
        // Match a mouse event on the body, when the left button is clicked
        // and the custom cell label is present
        CellLabelMouseEventMatcher mouseEventMatcher = new CellLabelMouseEventMatcher(GridRegion.BODY,MouseEventMatcher.LEFT_BUTTON, CUSTOM_CELL_LABEL5);
        // Inform the button painter of the click.
        uiBindingRegistry.registerMouseDownBinding(mouseEventMatcher, this.buttonCellPainter);
    }
}
```

I research source code , i find UiBindingRegistry this code:

private IMouseAction getMouseEventAction(MouseEventTypeEnum mouseEventType,
        MouseEvent event) {

```
// TODO: This code can be made more performant by mapping mouse bindings
// not only to the mouseEventType but
// also to the region that they are interested in. That way, given an
// area and an event we can narrow down the
// list of mouse bindings that need to be searched. -- Azubuko.Obele

try {
    LinkedList<MouseBinding> mouseEventBindings = this.mouseBindingsMap
            .get(mouseEventType);
    if (mouseEventBindings != null) {
        LabelStack regionLabels = this.natTable.getRegionLabelsByXY(event.x,
                event.y);

        for (MouseBinding mouseBinding : mouseEventBindings) {

            if (mouseBinding.getMouseEventMatcher().matches(this.natTable,
                    event, regionLabels)) {
                return mouseBinding.getAction();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}

If MouseDown event bing two event, Only the first to be able to perform.What should I do? I can think of the way is to select a row of data at the same time simulation of a cell button press action, But I don't know how to simulate the action of cell button.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want multiple actions to be performed on one interaction, you need to create a custom action that executes the both desired actions together.

I showed this here for performing selection and menu opening. [Showing NatTable context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748101/showing-nattable-context-menu)